# Image div overlay and preserving position during resize

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am placing a div on top of an responsive image, like this:
[image]

When I resize, I lose the position of the div tag, like this:
[image]

How can I resize this overlay div so that its size is proportionally resized and its position is maintained, when the screen size changes?

Comment: The second image is actually a smaller resized image of the top. SO displays it full width. So it may not be apparent from the images that the second image is a smaller version when I resize the screen

Comment: Use percentages for the position attributes (top, left?) and width/height to begin with ...?

Comment: Hmm..I m using percentage for width and height. I will try percentage for too and left as well. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the image in a container with percentage width and create a square using percentage and padding value. After that align the square using `position: absolute` and percentage value.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.lotus-image {
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  right: 20%;
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  border: 4px solid red;
  color: white;
}

.box-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src = "https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/blossoming-pink-lily-flowers-swamp-natural-background_548832-3024.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg" class="lotus-image" />
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-content">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```